# Creating a copy of the object for multiple comparison is a good practice?

Tags: c++

Suppose multiple comparations are required at once:

```
enum usermode
{
    active,
    standingby,
    inactive,
    dead,
    // many other modes....
};
class A
{
public:
    usermode mode;
};
```

function inherited pointer to class A (ptr points to A)

Method A:

```
if( ptr->mode == active || ptr->mode == standingby || ptr->mode == inactive || ptr->mode == dead ...//etc )
{
    //do something
}
```

Method B:

```
usermode cmpmode = ptr->mode;
if( cmpmode == active || cmpmode == standingby || cmpmode == inactive || cmpmode == dead ...//etc )
{
    //do something
}
```

Is it a good practice to do so?

Comment: The only case where I'd even consider your *Method B* is in multithreaded code so that I could acquire a lock, make a copy and release the lock before executing the `if`, instead of holding the lock over the duration of the `if`

Comment: Often code like this is organised to exploit bit flags where you can test multiple modes with a single comparison.  Similarly, you can arrange your enums in groups that need to be tested together (if it makes sense to do so) and compare with `>=` and/or `<=`.

Comment: @Prætorian I see, so the other thread could gain acccess to the object instead of waiting through the whole `if` statement. +1

Comment: Added an edit.  If this kind of check is common it may be best to simplify it a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case it simply cuts down on the amount of characters in the `if` statement expression, so whatever works and is most readable.

However, in the case of checking the return value of a function, I would stuff it into a variable and check that, i.e.,

```
auto ret = SomePossiblyExpensiveOperation();
if(ret != whatever && ret < something) {
    //...
}
```

Taking your `if` statement at face value, I would do this:

```
switch(ptr->mode) {
    case active:
    case standingby:
    case inactive:
    case dead:
        ptr->whatever();
        break;
    // other cases
    default:
        // something else
        break:
}
```

If this is a common check, you may want to make a special case for it, i.e.,

```
usermode any_mode = active | standingby | inactive | dead;

//...

if(ptr->mode & any_mode) {
    // whatever...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `mode` is just a member variable of the class, any decent compiler will generate the same code for both implementations. However, in general, these two approaches are not equivalent if you would use methods instead of fields (especially methods with side effects).

This is covered in more details at [Function calls vs. local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12494401/function-calls-vs-local-variables)

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be nicer if your class has a method to handle this directly

```
bool A::IsSomeState() const
{
  return mode == active || mode == standingby; // Etc
}
```

Comment: So your advice is to create an `IsXXX()` member function for every possible combination of that enumeration?

Comment: Depends if you're checking every possible combination of the enumeration. At least for the commonly used ones.